# Using arrays, storing data in arrays and outputting them

Tags: c++, arrays, output, storage

I am a newbie to C++ and currently writing a program that simulates a fixed number of particles traveling in a box (no collision as of yet, that means they should have the same coordinates theoretically). However, I am currently experiencing problems using arrays. How do I initialize, reference, store data and output them in this case?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void) {
float dlvelox;
float dlveloy;
float lvelox[1000];
float lveloy[1000];
float xcord[1000];
float ycord[1000];
float length;
float breadth;
int id;
int stepcount;
int step = 0;

/* Obtaining velocity */
{
printf("Enter the initial h velocity of the ball:\n");
scanf("%f", &dlvelox);
printf("Enter the initial v velocity of the ball:\n");
scanf("%f", &dlveloy);
std::fill_n(lvelox, dlvelox, -1);
std::fill_n(lveloy, dlveloy, -1);
}

/* Initializing box */
{
printf("Enter the length of box:\n");
scanf("%f", &length);
printf("Enter the breadth of box:\n");
scanf("%f", &breadth);
}

/* Obtain number of steps */
{
printf("Enter the number of steps wanted:\n");
scanf("%d", &stepcount);
}

/* Initial console display */
{
printf("\n");
printf("xcord, ycord, step\n");
printf("\n");

}

/* Loop method */
while ( step < stepcount )

for(id = 0; id < 1000; id++)
{
lveloy[id] = lveloy[id] - 9.81;
xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], step);

if ( ycord[id] < 0 )
{
lveloy[id] = (lveloy[id] * -1);
xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], step);
}

if ( ycord[id] > breadth )
{
lveloy[id] = (lveloy[id] * -1);
xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], step);
}

if ( xcord[id] < 0 )
{
lvelox[id] = (lvelox[id] * -1);
xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], step);
}

if ( xcord[id] > length )
{
lvelox[id] = (lvelox[id] * -1);
xcord[id] = xcord[id] + lvelox[id];
ycord[id] = ycord[id] + lveloy[id];
printf("%f, %f, %d\n", xcord[id], ycord[id], step);
}

step = step + 1;

}

if ( step == stepcount )
{
return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: what is your exact issue? what kind of error you get?

Comment: Instead of outputting 1000 values of xcord and ycord per step, I get only 3. They're all random numbers that do not make sense.

Comment: Even more importantly, is your `TAB` key broken?

Comment: While most of the code is C, some of it is C++. You should probably try and stick to one language only.

Comment: The UK has done with Brownian motion

Comment: That is what I am trying to simulate :)

Comment: There's no `<algorithm>` or `std::` in C. You are probably using some other product with a confusingly similar name. You should decide if that's what you actually want.

Comment: Oh how do I initialize all elements of an array to a specific value in C?

Answer (score 1):

With this line

```
std::fill_n(lvelox, dlvelox, -1);
```

you initialize `dlvelox` number of entries in the `lvelox` array.

But then you loop

```
for(id = 0; id < 1000; id++)
```

using entries in the arrays that are not initialized. The uninitialized entries in the arrays contain indeterminate values, and can't be used as that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! May I know which arrays are not initialized? Haha sorry I am new to C programming!

Comment: @WanDingYao No local variables in C or C++ are initialized automatically.

Comment: After initializing the values of xcord and ycord to 0 using "float xcord[1000] = {0};", I still get values of 0 for 2 particles only :(

Comment: @WanDingYao Don't forget the rest of `lveloy` and `lvelox`.